# How to decode back formatted string?

Tags: java, string, formatting, string-formatting

I am formatting my string like this:

```
final String identity = String.format("%04X-%04X", random.nextInt(), random.nextInt(), "CORP");
```

Now if I know value of `identity` variable, is there any way I can get CORP value back by interpreting it somehow?

```
final String identity = "7C8804DE-5B4CC287";
// print out CORP here? but how?
```

How to extract `CORP` value back from the identity string?

Comment: The question is unclear.  If all you have is the result, `CORP` was discarded since there was no `%s` format to include it in the result.  It is gone.  Why would you think there was any "residue" in the result?  Also, the `%04X` should probably be `%08X` or you'll get inconsistent results if there are leading zeros in the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the question is that what you are asking is impossible.

The string `"CORP"` is not included in the result of the formatting.  You seem to believe there's some "residue" in the output that could be reconstituted back into the input, but this is not true.  There was no `%s` format specifier that caused the string to be included in the result, so it is gone.

Also, the format specifier `%04X` should probably be `%08X`, to avoid inconsistent result string lengths if the `int` values end up having leading zeros in hex.

Comment: if I pass `%s` as well then will it be possible? Like this, I mean `"%04X-%04X-%s"`

Comment: If you do that the output will be (for your example) `"7C8804DE-5B4CC287-CORP"` -- If that output is acceptable then you would be able to use `String#split("-")` to recover the individual fields.

Comment: yes that's what I meant. Sorry for making it unclear. So I can split on `-` and extract the last part. got it.

Comment: Use `split("-", 3)` so it doesn't split on any `-` characters in the 3rd part.

Comment: my third word won't have any `-`, it will always be a string.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Jim's answer, format strings are not reversible *in general*.  To understand why, consider this:

```
final String s = String.format("%d%d", random.nextInt(), random.nextInt());
```

This might produce a string "12345678".  But you cannot tell with certainty if the original numbers were `{1, 2345678}` or `{12, 345678}` or ...

If there was sufficient unambiguous punctuation in the format string, then it may be possible to "reverse" a formatted text.  However, I am not aware of any general "format reverser" libraries for Java.

---

With your corrected format string, there is sufficient punctuation to allow the "CORP" string to be extracted by a hypothetical extractor library.  But as I said, I'm not aware of any such library.  The normal way to deal with this kind of task is to implement a simple parser; e.g. using `String::split` or `Pattern` / `Matcher`.  But in the cases where the format produces an ambiguous or lossy string, there is no way to recover the original information.